# Update DOM and send current time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I am trying to send the current time when the button is clicked but i get the time when the page was loaded instead the current time. The button submits a form on Google sheets with an API.

PHP code to get the time:

```
<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens"); 
    echo date("d-m-Y"). " at ".date("h:i:sa"); 
?>
```

Complete code:

```
<input id="timeSubmit" class=" w3-text-black" name="time submitted"/>

<script>
    $( "#button" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();  

        $("#timeSubmit").val('<?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");
        echo date("d-m-Y"). " at ".date("h:i:sa")); ?>';
    });
</script>
```

Problem:

I get the time the DOM was loaded instead the current time when the button was clicked.

Comment: of course, because PHP pre-processes the page a single time, before it is sent to the browser - you'll need to use javascript `Date` object to get the date in the browser

Comment: just change the code with this: $("#timeSubmit").val(new Date())

Answer (score 1):

You are using a server-sided page to set the date and time for your timezone which translates it into a static time (e.g. the time your user opened the page as it was generated for them at said time)

You can use a client-side library like momentjs (or just new Date()) to set the date whenever the button is being clicked. This populates the field with the current browser's time.